# How to add view in window which will show on swipe of every view controller?

Tags: swift, io, uiwindow

I have scenario like I have many view controllers with navigation controller and this navigation controller is root view of window. Now no matter which view controller is on screen if I swipe then one view will show with some options. So what should be approach to develop this? So can I do that make navigation controller as root view of window and add 1 view in window and also add swipe gesture in window ? So when swipe left that view which is add in window will be shown and on click of any option my new view controller will be pushed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i follow what you want, but lets see what i can think of. You should be using storyboards for simplicity's sake. You should drag a navigation controller out of the right side view. You should select this controller and go into the properties tag and with in the "View Controller" section there is an "Is Initial View Controller" check box. Select that and ios will automatically make this as the root view controller of your window. From here you should make a subclass for the navigation controller. Call it something like "application navigation controller" or "master navigation controller" and override "viewdidload". Since this is the root view controller and you never plan on changing the root this should only call "viewdidload" once. From that function you should allocate 2 swipe gestures. One for right and the other for left.

That should take care of setting a navigation controller as your root and setting up the swiping for left and right. Now if you want a view with in your navigation controller you will have to go into the storyboard and add a View Controller object to the screen. After you do that, right click on the navigation controller and drag it over the newly added viewController. Releasing the mouse button should make a pop up where you can select "root view controller", that is the root of the navigation controller. Add your views with in here, which by your explanation it sounds like you want a tableview.

From your question it's rather hard to determine what exactly you are going for. It seems as though you want a standard stack of view controllers controlled by a navigation controller. With a side menu. If that is the case then you will have to either use a 3rd party library because apple doesn't provide a side menu widget. Then things get more complicated, the root of your application should be only a single view controller with 2 container views and then add view controllers to these containers. The main container would hold the navigation controller explained above. The other container, aka the side menu, would hold the view controller with a tableview in it. In the storyboard you just right the container view and drag over/release on the view controller you want  and then select the option "view controller". You will have to set up auto layout and animate the constraints upon swiping.

I could go on for a while, but maybe you could use some of this knowledge as a means of completing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Add a swipe gesture to each VC that you want the swipeVC to appear on, in the swipe action function call presentViewController which will present the view controller outside the nav stack.

When you're done with this VC, call presentingViewController.dismissViewController and in prepare for segue to get back to the presenting vc, get the navigation controller and ask it to present the next vc in the stack.